# can't right click and add a view to action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

When I create a new action method and right click it doesn't show me the "add view" option, it shows me the "go to view" option and when I click that it tells me "unable to find a matching view".

Creating a view on its own with a name that fits the action method works but I want to create strongly typed views and as far as I know I can't do that without the wizard thing that opens when you create view from an action method.

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Like this is how the most basic action method looks like right?

Comment: That's a known _feature_ of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @AndreiV so am i just screwed for the foreseeable future? should i downgrade or should i wait for it to be fixed?

Comment: Well... can't really answer that. If that's a deal breaker, then downgrade. I see it as an opportunity to learn how to create extensions. VS 2015 is said to be _friendlier_ to extension development :).

Comment: I have VS2015 too. But I have `Add View...` menu. Something wrong with your VS

Comment: You can create a Strongly typed view without the wizard help. May this post can be helpful.                                                                                              http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views

Comment: So... any idea when they will be adding the feature back?

Comment: Your project isn't running is it? I've had that same error when the project is running. You can't make modifications to the project while it is running. Stop the project, and then the Add View button is re-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Scotch comment on the question, it might be that you're in debug mode (f5) so stop it (shift+f5) before right click -> add